# Yocto Uboot CONFIG_USE_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE xxd: not found

Tags: yocto, u-boot

I'm trying to compile the U-boot 2020.07 with option CONFIG_USE_DEFAULT_ENV_FILE=y and with the path to file which contains new U-boot environments records.

> u-boot-suniv-spiflash/1_v2020.07-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build
> obj=scripts/basic | /bin/sh: 1: xxd: not found

I try to compile manually the same U-boot with the same Yocto toolchain and the compilation success U-boot works with replaced env records.

The problem is related to Makefile. I found somewhere some solution which allows me to compile success but with empty environment records in U-boot after boot-up.

The problematic syntax is

```
define filechk_defaultenv.h
    (grep -v '^#' | \
     grep -v '^$$' | \
     tr '\n' '\0' | \
     sed -e 's/\\\x0\s*//g' | \
     xxd -i ; echo ", 0x00" ; )
ended
```

the solution from internet is

```
define filechk_defaultenv.h
    (grep -v '^#' | \
     grep -v '^$$' | \
     tr '\n' '\0' | \
     sed -e 's/\\\x0\s*//g' | \
     xxd -i | \
     sed -r 's/([0-9a-f])$$/\1, /'; \
     echo "0x00" ; )
ended
```

Unfortunately, these environment records are empty after U-Boot's start-up.

Do You have knowledge of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: xxd is a command line tool. The reported error indicates that it is not installed on your system. On Ubuntu you can install it with 'sudo apt-get install xxd'.

Comment: xdd is installed on system. When typeing from console (grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^$' | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's/\\\x0\s*//g' | xxd -i ; echo ", 0x00" ; ) < /home/mw/temp/git-uboot-yocto/uboot.env > ~/good.txt it generated good results.

Comment: The problem is solved forgotten to add "DEPENDS += " xxd-native" into a u-boot.bb. Thanks Xypron